# C list multithreaded synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading, list, synchronization

I have a multi-threaded C server-client TCP project.
Each thread (except the main thread) is responsible for a single client and I have a global list that contains information about each client (socket file descriptor, etc).
The main thread is always adding new nodes to the list when a new client connects (this thread adds a new element to the head of the list).
All other threads do the following:

- They frequently sweep the list to get all clients' socket descriptors in order to "broadcast" some data to all clients
- When a client disconnects, the responsible thread deletes the client's node in the list

What synchronization method is most suited for this problem?
I already thought of having a mutex for each node, and if a thread needed to delete a node from the middle of the list, it would block 3 mutexes (the mutex of the node which is being deleted and the mutexes of the adjacent nodes). But I also saw somewhere that conditional variables were suitable for multi threaded lists.

Note: I would like a solution that won't block the whole list, which makes it inaccessible to other threads

Thanks

Comment: Could you simplify the problem by having only one thread (the main thread, for example) be responsible for removing nodes from the list?

Comment: Just use a _single_ mutex for the entire list. Use `pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock` and keep the code between them [to do insertions/deletions] _short_. The amount of time spent blocked is small enough that it doesn't matter much. (i.e. keep it simple [and robust]).

Comment: @JoelCornett still, there's the problem with the other threads sweeping the list

Comment: @CraigEstey that would block the whole thread.. The other threads couldn't sweep the list until the insertions/deletions are done :/

Comment: @francis2tm true, you’d need to read lock the list as well. What is the purpose of the sweeping?

Comment: @JoelCornett send some data to all client

Comment: It's puzzling that your worker threads ever need to communicate with clients other than the one they're servicing.  Why is that?  Just a condition of the classroom exercise, or is there a 'real world' case for having random child threads broadcast to all clients?

Comment: @francis2tm So each client thread is accessing every client in order to broadcast data?

Comment: @JoelCornett yes, the broadcasts are very frequent

Comment: @JonathanLeffler condition of a classroom exercise yes

Comment: Just use a single read-write mutex. It sounds like you will be reading from the list far more often than you write.

Comment: @JoelCornett maybe I'm complicating things right?

Comment: When I authored facil.io, I decided to use an array instead of a linked list - this solved a lot of issues, minimizing lock contention, allowing a per-socket lock as well as providing easy access to the data. The array could be dynamically managed (i.e., with a global lock) - or, as I ended up doing, the size of the array could define the concurrency limits on the server.

Comment: What is the maximum number of concurrent clients you'll ever need to handle?  If it is less than about 10K (which it probably is), you can afford to use an array instead of a linked list, even if each element of the array occupies a couple of kilobytes, which is also rather generous — you'd be looking at 20 MiB of data with 10240 clients * 2 KiB data per client (where you're more likely to be using less than 256 bytes per client, and probably less than 128 clients).  I ask about this to work out how much space you'll need to stored the scanned descriptors for a broadcast. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Even with 10K clients, you'll only need 40 KiB memory for the array of descriptors, which is peanuts on a machine capable of handling 10K clients in the first place.  So, you'd scan the list or array into an array of descriptors.  If the broadcaster finds that a client is dead, they can simply move on to the next since there's a thread dedicated to the management of the client, and that thread will also find that its dead.  Or the broadcaster could take steps to invalidate that client/socket.